# ASP.NET MVC view with a table row view to open a pdf file without leaving the view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an ActionLink on my view page which opens a pdf drawing. The drawing files opens without issue but it then updates the page to the Html link. Is there a way to prevent that so the original page remains static and doesn't change?

Table view:

```
<td>
@if (item.DrawingNumber.Contains("CAD") || (item.DrawingNumber.Contains("DRG")))
{
    @Html.ActionLink("PDF", "OpenDrawingPDF", new { DNumber = item.DrawingNumber })
}
</td>
```

Controller code:

```
public void OpenDrawingPDF(string DNumber)
{
    string Path = @"\\Ser1\Company\10 - Production\Production Drawings\CAD pdf\";

    string Folder = DNumber.Substring(4,2) + @"\";

    // Open the pdf file
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Path + Folder + DNumber + ".pdf");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the easiest solution is to simply open the pdf in a new tab. You can do that by adding an additional parameter to the ActionLink method:

```
<td>
@if (item.DrawingNumber.Contains("CAD") || (item.DrawingNumber.Contains("DRG")))
{
    @Html.ActionLink("PDF", "OpenDrawingPDF", new { DNumber = item.DrawingNumber }, new { target = "_blank" })
}
</td>
```

Comment: Matt, thank you for the suggestion but that is not going to be a workable solution from a users point of view.